# Automation project does not recognize and run feature file

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, specflow

Currently I created a unit test project in visual studio to automate my tests with C #, Selenium Web Driver and SpecFlow.

After writing my .feature file in BDD and generate step definitions, when running all the tests, they are not recognized in the test manager and I have the following error in IntelliSense.

```
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\peter01\source\repos\AutomatedTests\ExampleProject\UnitTest1.cs'.
```

My project is already configured output type "Class Library", and i deleted the UnitTest1.cs file when I created the project.

I need the test project to recognize and run all tests from my Login.feature file

My project have only one feature File "Login.feature"

```
Feature: Login  

    Scenario: Login Success
        Given i access website
        When do login with user
        | user    | password|
        | user123 | pass123 |
        Then show message
```

And LoginStepDefinition.cs

```cs
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using System;
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

    namespace ExampleNamespaceXXXX

        {
            [Binding]    

            public class LoginSteps
            {        
                [Given(@"i access website")]
                public void Example1()
                {
                    example line code
                }

                [When(@"do login with user")]
                public void Example2(Table table)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        example line code
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchElementException)
                    {
                        example line code
                    }
                }

                [Then(@"show message")]
                public void Example3()
                {
                    example line code
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: btw, which version of specflow are you using? If you try to add new feature file, do you see code behind (.feature.cs file) of .feature file? There were issues with regenerating feature files.

Answer (score 2):

If you want VS to detect all your tests then you need to use test adapter,

### You can configure the test project in different ways

> 1. If you are want to use *MStest* runner then add **MSTest.TestAdapter** and **MSTest.TestFramework** to your project as a dependency.
> 2. If you want *SpecRunner* then add the **SpecRun.Runner** package  to the packages.config
>      file of your SpecFlow projects. You might need to restart Visual
>      Studio to see your tests.

For more reference, you can go through official link:  https://specflow.org/documentation/Troubleshooting-Visual-Studio-Integration/

---

### In My case I have created a test project using MSTest Adapter and SpecFlow to run all my feature files, If you want to give a try follow below steps:

> 1. create new project of type MSTest. [VS to create new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Tl7.png)
> 2. Enter the project name and location to save your test project.
> 3. By this time you will be able to see all the basic dependencies in you project. [default dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3QvJ.png)
> 4. Now, just add **SpecFlow** and 
>      **SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation** dependencies to your project scope via Nuget package manager to get detected by your test runner and to run
>      all your features files.

Now all the basic configuration is done and you need to build your project to run your test project.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means Visual Studio is referencing a file that does not exist on disk. You need to right click on that file in Solution Explorer and choose "Exclude from Project". Be sure to "Save All" afterward excluding the file.

This can happen if you delete a file outside Visual Studio. The .csproj file that tells VS which files get included will not get updated, and Visual Studio tried to compile a file that doesn't exist.